# How to get title with class name

Tags: jquery, title

**How to get value "Unlike" in this code**

```
<div class="pluginButtonContainer">
<div class="pluginButtonImage">
<button type="submit">
<i class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOff img sp_plugin-button sx_plugin-button_chblue"></i>
<i class="pluginButtonIcon pluginButtonXOn img sp_plugin-button sx_plugin-button_xblue" title="Unlike"></i>
</button></div>
<span class="pluginButtonLabel">Like</span>
</div>
```

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

Title is an attribute, so can be retrieved using [.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like:

```
var title = $('i.sx_plugin-button_xblue').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()`to retrieve the text inside the `i` element

Try this

```
$('i[title=Unlike]').text()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cSrC7/)

Get title

```
$('i.sx_plugin-button_xblue').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var title = $(".pluginButtonIcon.pluginButtonXOn.img.sp_plugin-button.sx_plugin-button_xblue").attr("title");

 alert(title);
```